# Cannot precisely resize elements in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to align my horizontal and vertical lines within my group header. For some reason, I cannot do it precisely. What might be causing this? Please see images below - there is no in-between that I can resize the horizontal line to (this is zoom 400%). Earlier in other sections I was able to precisely align/change size of similar lines. This problem applies to elements such as text objects, too.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal default is to 'Snap To Grid'.

- You can turn off that option under ***File, Options...***
- Or hold down the shift key to allow smooth dragging/resizing
- Or move the other object so it also snaps to grid

Comment: Good. I forgot to mention that the File, Options... dialog also allows you to adjust the grid cell size (as well as turn on/off grid visibility in Design/Preview views.